# Javascript Map Filter Issue

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, filter, google-fusion-tables

Right now I am using the Google Maps JavaScript API V3 to filter map results. I have two javascript drop down menus. When one dropdown option value is selected, the map filters to that setting. So if I select the business type "Social Services" the map will show only this type of business. The second filters for a different subject. So if the second dropdown menu is selected, it will filter to this option value. The problem is, when the second or first is selected, it disregards the other in its filtering. For example, I would like users to be able to filter "Social Services" from the first menu and "Opportunity" from the second. This would display locations that meet both criteria. Right now users can only select one or the other.

Here is the page:

[LTI Maps](http://www.kynikosdesign.com/ltimaps/)

Here is the code:

```
    <html> 
<head> 
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /> 
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Met Sacramento Internship Map</title> 

<!-- Style --> 
<style> 
  body { font-family: Arial, sans-serif; }
  #map_canvas { height: 500px; width:600px; }
</style> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var tableid = 567682;
    var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(567682); 

  function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38.59970036588819, -121.541748046875);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        myOptions);
          layer.setMap(map);
  }
    //Change the query based on the user's selection
function interestMap(interest) {
 layer.setQuery("SELECT Address, 'Interest Area' FROM " + tableid + " WHERE 'Interest Area' CONTAINS '" + interest + "'"); 
}
function statusMap(status) {
 layer.setQuery("SELECT Address, 'Status' FROM " + tableid + " WHERE 'Status' CONTAINS '" + status + "'"); 
}
</script>

 </script> 

</head> 
<body onload="initialize();">  
  Internship Status <select onchange="interestMap(this.value);"> 
    <option value="">Interest Areas</option>
<option value="Aerospace">Aerospace</option>
<option value="Animals">Animals</option>
<option value="Architecture">Architecture</option>
<option value="Art/Music/Theatre">Art/Music/Theatre</option>
<option value="Athletics and Martial Arts">Athletics</option>
<option value="Automotive and Transportation">Automotive</option>
<option value="Business">Business</option>
<option value="Community Development">Community Development</option>
<option value="Computers">Computers</option>
<option value="Cosmetology">Cosmetology</option>
<option value="Culinary">Culinary</option>
<option value="Education">Education</option>
<option value="Government and Politics">Politics</option>
<option value="Health Science">Health Science</option>
<option value="Hospitality/Tourism/Event Planning">Event Planning</option>
<option value="Law and Public Safety">Law and Public Safety</option>
<option value="Marketing">Marketing</option>
<option value="Media and Information Technology">Media</option>
<option value="Photography">Photography</option>
<option value="Science and Technology">Science and Technology
</option>
<option value="Social Services">Social Services</option>
  </select>
   Status <select onchange="statusMap(this.value);"> 
    <option value="">Status</option>
<option value="BEING PURSUED">Being Pursued</option>
<option value="HAS INTERN">Has Intern</option>
<option value="NOT TAKING">Not Taking</option>
<option value="OPPORTUNITY">Opportunity</option>
<option value="OVER 18">Over 18</option>
<option value="POTENTIAL?">Potential</option>
<option value="SEE NOTES">See Notes</option>


  </select>
  <div id="map_canvas"></div>

</body> 
</html>
```

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having 2 different functions for filtering I would create one that filters based on values from both dropdown lists.

Something like this:

```
function filterResults(){
    var interest = document.getElementById('ddl-interest').value;
    var status = document.getElementById('ddl-status').value;

    layer.setQuery("SELECT Address, 'Interest Area' FROM " + tableid + 
    " WHERE 'Interest Area' CONTAINS '" + interest + "' AND 'Status' CONTAINS '" + status + "'");
}
```

Then you obviously need to give your dropdown lists ids 'ddl-interest' and 'ddl-status' and call 'filterResults' method on onchange event.